# how to convert Array of any datatype into comma seprated strings in scala

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark, int

My current code is :

```
schema.fields.foreach(f => {
                              if (f.dataType.typeName == "array") {
                                throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${f.name} column is ArrayType, " +
                                  "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")
                              }
                            })
```

currently we dont support arrays in csv but now want to support array of any datatype  by converting it to Strings. String should be separated by comma.

Test case:

```
test("testArrayInSchema") {
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      TestDataSetArrays(
        Array(1, 2, 3),
        Array("a", "b", "c"),
        Array(new Timestamp(0), new Timestamp(1), new Timestamp(3))
      )
    ))
    assertThrows[ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException] {
            writeDataFrame(df)

    }
```

Now we need to remove this exception as we need to support arrays by converting them into string

Comment: what if its nested structure again? like array<struct> or array<map>

Comment: @Someshwar Kale we will have data like above mentioned in test case so can we do below check to check if array<anytype> is coming then convert it into string separated by comma :
schema.fields.foreach(field =>
          field.dataType match {
                    case arrayType: ArrayType =>
                      // convert array<any> to string
                      concat_ws(",", col(field.name)).as(field.name)
                    case _ => col(field.name)

                    }
                )

Answer (score 0):

To convert the array into comma separated string you can use mkString(", ") method
for example:

```
 val arr = Array("test1", "test2")
 arr.mkString(", ")
```